# C++ enum class std::size_t implicit conversion

Tags: c++, tuples, std, enum-class

I have defined a tuple and its indices by creating an enum class:

```
/** parameter { key ; value1 ; value1 ; } */
using Parameter = std::tuple<unsigned, unsigned, unsigned>;
enum class ParameterKey : std::size_t {
    KEY = 0,
    VALUE1 = 1,
    VALUE2 = 2
};
```

Now I would like to get a value from this tuple:

```
const auto& key = std::get<ParameterKey::KEY>(*parameterPointer);
```

I thought the implicit conversion from `int` to `std::size_t` is ensured by the `: std::size_t` syntax :

```
enum class ParameterKey : std::size_t {
    ....
}
```

but I'm getting this error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘get<KEY>(std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>&)’
```

This works fine, but it's too garrulous:

```
const auto& key = std::get<static_cast<unsigned>(ParameterKey::KEY)>(*parameterPointer);
```

Comment: There is no implicit conversion from an enum class to anything, you could create  your own `get`.

Comment: Okay, but what's the purpose of the `: std::size_t` syntax than?

Comment: @sukovanej to specify the [underlying_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion here. From [enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped
>   enumerator to integral types, although static_cast may be used to
>   obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

So, you have to use `static_cast`.

---

There are some workarounds which are based on `static_cast`. For instance, one might make use of [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type):

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto get_idx(T value)
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(value);
}
```

And then:

```
const auto& key = std::get<get_idx(ParameterKey::KEY)>(*parameterPointer);
```

Comment: You need to add `constexpr` to `get_idx` to make this work.

Comment: @Holt yep, exactly!

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of `enum class` is to not be implicitly convertible to `int`, so there is no implicit conversion.

You could create your own `get` version:

```
template <ParameterKey key, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) get(Tuple &&tuple) {
    return std::get<static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<ParameterKey>>(key)>(tuple);
}
```

Then:

```
const auto& key = get<ParameterKey::KEY>(*parameterPointer);
```

Comment: That's not the whole purpose. It also fixes the incorrect scoping of `enum` and allows you to specify the underlying type explicitly. So there's definitely reason to want `enum class` and also want implicit conversion.

Comment: @Timmmm You can specify underlying type for standard enums. Agree with the scoping of the standard enums, but the purpose of `enum class` is not to fix this, it's just a side-effect of introducing a new features with 20 years of feedback on existing ones. IMO, unless you're working on very low-level code, you don't want implicit conversion for your `enum class`.

Comment: @Holt, thanks, I had somehow not noticed that underlying type can be specified for standard enums.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the conversion implicit by creating specialization of an array/vector that accepts this specific enum as an argument:

```
template <typename ElementType, typename EnumType>
class enumerated_array: array<ElementType, static_cast<size_t>(EnumType::size_)>
{
    using ParentType = array<ElementType, static_cast<size_t>(EnumType::size_)>;
public:
    ElementType& operator[](EnumType enumerator)
    {
        return ParentType::operator[](static_cast<size_t>(enumerator));
    }
    const ElementType& operator[](EnumType enumerator) const
    {
        return ParentType::operator[](static_cast<size_t>(enumerator));
    }
};

// --------------------------------
// and that's how you use it:

enum class PixelColor: size_t { Red, Green, Blue, size_ };
enumerated_array<uint8_t, PixelColor> pixel;
// Can't use any other enum class as an index
pixel[PixelColor::Green] = 255;
```

Also, while this is not a topic of this question, this approach synergies really well with enum iterators:

```
template <typename T>
class EnumRangeType
{
public:
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        Iterator(size_t value):
            value_(value)
        { }

        T operator*() const
        {
            return static_cast<T>(value_);
        }

        void operator++()
        {
            ++value_;
        }

        bool operator!=(Iterator another) const
        {
            return value_ != another.value_;
        }

    private:
        size_t value_;
    };

    static Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(0);
    }

    static Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(static_cast<size_t>(T::size_));
    }
};
template <typename T> constexpr EnumRangeType<T> enum_range;

// --------------------------------
// and that's how you use it:

void make_monochrome(enumerated_array<uint8_t, PixelColor>& pixel)
{
    unsigned int total_brightness = 0;
    for (auto color: enum_range<PixelColor>)
        total_brightness += pixel[color];

    uint8_t average_brightness = total_brightness/3;
    for (auto color: enum_range<PixelColor>)
        pixel[color] = average_brightness;
}
```